# Проблема с цветами favicon

Tags: веб-программирование, изображения

Есть favicon.png, которую я создал для своего сайта и при сохранении её с ICC-профилем она выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А после загрузки на сервер она превращается в это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тот же самый эффект можно получить, сохранив картинку без ICC профиля. В чём прикол? Почему браузер меняет цвет моей иконки?

Comment: видимо сервер зарезает качество по дефолту

Comment: @PauloBerezini сервер тут ни при чём. Если запросить favicon напрямую, то она отобразится нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изображения для иконок нужно сохранять не просто как `.png`, а делать это через *Экспортировать* -> *Сохранить для Web*, отметив при этом пункт **Преобразовать в sRGB**.